# can't find column stats for newly created table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, execution-plan, statistics, recompile

I am trying to simulate a plan recompilation due to auto update stats which is triggered when threshold(500 + 20 percent modifications) reached.

database current settings are:

[image]

I started with creating a simple table:

```
create table recomp(num int)
go
```

Then I insert some rows:

```
insert into recomp
values (5)
go 100
```

and run my query below 5 times (I used **where 1 = (select 1)**) for full optimization:

```
select * from recomp
where 1 = (select 1)
```

in my plan cache I have the following:

[image]

Now the interesting part, I again insert new rows in order to trigger auto update stats for **num** column of the recomp table:

```
insert into recomp
values (8)
go 500
```

Here stats for num column has updated. The next what I am going to do is run my select query:

```
select * from recomp
where 1 = (select 1)
```

When I check my plan cache:

[image]

and an event which captures recompiles:

[image]

my question is: where can I find **stats** for **num** column?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The optimizer doen't need any stats to optimize those queries, so none are created.

> When the automatic create statistics option, AUTO_CREATE_STATISTICS is
>   ON, the Query Optimizer creates statistics on individual columns in
>   the query predicate, **as necessary**, to improve cardinality estimates
>   for the query plan.

[AUTO_CREATE_STATISTICS Option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/statistics/statistics?view=sql-server-ver15#AutoUpdateStats)

Try something like

```
select *
from recomp
where num = 4
```

And you should see a statistic created.